# spring webflux how get request body in webfilter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

i want to get the request body in a webfilter.

now, when the request body is to large,

```
final Flux<DataBuffer> body = exchange.getRequest().getBody();
```

this body has size 555,

how to get the request body in the webfilter?

Comment: Do you get an error when the request body is too large?

Comment: Lost a part of the data~

Comment: @xiaoyu all relevant details added because of comments should be put int he text of the question with an [edit].

Comment: You should not buffer the whole request body in a filter. What if the request body is very large? What if the request body is an infinite stream? Even if the request body is small, you’re basically breaking the back pressure feature in your application and paying a big performance price for that.

Comment: tks,now in the webfilter,cant get body?